# 3D animated TV show in which three kids have superpowers of animals

Tags: story-identification, tv, powers

This was a 3D animated TV show with three kids who have superpowers of animals. The main character had bright orange hair and he loves cats and feeds strays. He has cat powers where he has agility and can jump high.

It’s not [*PJ Masks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PJ_Masks). It looks older.

Comment: Hi Purple, when did you see this? When do you guess it was made? Was it an English show?

Comment: I tried making the question title more clear. Feel free to revert the edit if you think it changed the intent of the question.